# From which class category filter is added to the filter groups used for aggregation : magento 2 layered navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, magento-2.1.3, multiselect-attribute

From which class category filter is added to the filter groups used for aggregation : magento 2 layered navigation. The aggregation and search classes are used for getting the count of products in each filter in layered navigation. But when the category filter is added to the group of filters which is later used by the search Class.

Comment: This may help you Pankaj https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2016/11/29/add-category-filter-to-product-grid-in-magento2/

Comment: I am looking for layered navigation related category filter. The link you posted is not about the same.

Comment: Okay. I will do some r & d and mg tula sangte

Comment: ok. That will be great.